# Erase answer and start over JS Calculator

Tags: javascript, function, math, calculator

I made a Javascript calculator, and I'm trying to figure out how to erase the value of result after the equal button is pressed, so the next calculation doesn't interfere with the previous.  For example, put **2+2** in the calculator, and press equal.  Then, try to do **8+8**.  See how you get 48?  I want the value to be cleared before the function starts.

Here is the calculator on jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/J5bwP/

```
var result = document.calc.result;

function runNum(x) {
result.value += x;
}
function runPlus() {
result.value += "+";
}
function runSubtract() {
result.value += "-";
}
function runMultiply() {
result.value += "*";
}
function runDivide() {
result.value += "/";
}
function runClear() {
result.value = "";
}
function runDec() {
result.value += ".";
}
function runNegate() {
result.value = result.value - (result.value * 2);
}
function theAnswer() {
var evalo = eval(result.value);
result.value = evalo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/nASmq/)***

There are definitely things I would suggest changing. Such as using `eval` to do the math, or using inline javascript. Aside from those things, to allow for clearing the calculator when entering a new calculation, I would suggest using something like this:

```
var reset = false;
function clear(){
 if(reset){
  result.value = "";
  reset = false;
 }
```

and then apply this logic in your methods such as

```
function runNum(x) {
 clear();
 result.value += x;
}
```

and set the reset flag in the equal button

```
function theAnswer() {
 var evalo = eval(result.value);
 result.value = evalo;
 reset = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using other function on Ac.

you need to give eventListener to Ac button like this.

```
acButton.addEventListener("click",()=>Location.reload());
```

OR OR OR
you have to give null to your main display.

like This,

```
AcButton.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
    mainDisplayOutputScreen.TextContent = null);
```